# Javascript function returns undefined instead of int

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

My js/jquery function does not work properly and instead of INT returns undefined.

```
function __getLastSelectedCategory(table_id) {
    if ( jQuery('.categories_table[data-table-id="1"]').find('td.active').length > 0 ){
        console.log('check1');
        if (table_id != '0') {
            console.log('check2');
            var checkTableId = parseInt(table_id) - 1;
            var table = jQuery('.cl_categories_display ').find('table[data-table-id="' + checkTableId + '"]');

            if (table.find('td.active').length > 0) {
                console.log('check3');
                console.log('table id: ' + table.find('td.active').data('category-id'));
                return table.find('td.active').data('category-id');
            } else {
                console.log('check4');
                __getLastSelectedCategory(checkTableId);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('check5');
            var lastTable = jQuery('.cl_categories_display ').find('table:last');
            var lastTableId = lastTable.data('table-id');

            if (lastTable.find('td.active').length > 0) {
                console.log('check6');
                return lastTable.find('td.active').data('category-id');
            } else {
                console.log('check7');
                __getLastSelectedCategory(lastTableId);
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log('check8');
        return null;
    }
}
```

when I run this function I see in console:

- check 1
- check 5
- check 7
- check 1
- check 2
- check 3
- table id: 1
- last cat: undefined

so the recursion works fine, but instead of integer (console printed "table id: 1") ir returns undefined. What could be wrong?

Comment: you're not returning the results of the recursive calls.

Comment: so where is the problem? becouse you just typed that and there is no info what do you mean.

Comment: `return __getLastSelectedCategory(lastTableId);`

Comment: no bro. as you can see after third check it returns me ID of the table "check 3" : `table id: 1` and there recursion is stopping

Comment: If you exit the function without an explicit `return` statement - which will happen in the cases that your code makes a recursive call - the returned value will be `undefined`. You don't have to believe me, but it will take you just a few seconds to try it,

Comment: If i will exit function after "check 7" it will not return me the result I need. That's why the recursion calls itself again and search for nearest result. And how it can be explained when `console.log('table id: ' + table.find('td.active').data('category-id'));` prints `table id: 1` and just after it calling `return table.find('td.active').data('category-id');` returns me undefined? Sorry for bad english, maybe I'm not understanding what you want to say well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `return` from recurse call: It returned value from the inner function to the outer, but did not return it from outer function to the caller. Try this:

```
    function __getLastSelectedCategory(table_id) {
        if ( jQuery('.categories_table[data-table-id="1"]').find('td.active').length > 0 ){
        console.log('check1');
        if (table_id != '0') {
            console.log('check2');
            var checkTableId = parseInt(table_id) - 1;
            var table = jQuery('.cl_categories_display ').find('table[data-table-id="' + checkTableId + '"]');

            if (table.find('td.active').length > 0) {
            console.log('check3');
            console.log('table id: ' + table.find('td.active').data('category-id'));
            return table.find('td.active').data('category-id');
            } else {
            console.log('check4');
            return __getLastSelectedCategory(checkTableId);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('check5');
            var lastTable = jQuery('.cl_categories_display ').find('table:last');
            var lastTableId = lastTable.data('table-id');

            if (lastTable.find('td.active').length > 0) {
            console.log('check6');
            return lastTable.find('td.active').data('category-id');
            } else {
            console.log('check7');
            return __getLastSelectedCategory(lastTableId);
            }
        }
        } else {
        console.log('check8');
        return null;
        }
    }
```